# restarting php5-fpm on ubuntu 14.04 with chef

Tags: ubuntu, php-fpm, upstart, chef-solo

I have this in my chef recipe:

```
service 'php5-fpm' do
  supports :restart => true
  action [ :enable, :start ]
end
```

However my recipe now barfs in Ubuntu 14.04, as "/etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart" does not work on Ubuntu 14.04 (it returns with 1 and there is no message).

How do I get my chef recipe to restart and manage the php5-fpm service?

Answer (score 2):

Solved by adding the following to my service in chef:

"provider Chef::Provider::Service::Upstart"

This is really going to start getting annoying when some services let you use init.d and others force you to use upstart.

Comment: You can look forward to more fun as Ubuntu migrates to systemd. :-)